Need a sanity check on finding expected value of a weird distribution
Context: There's an item in a game that has $360$ durability (at $0$, the item breaks). Every time the item is used, there is a probability that the item will take damage. The distribution that describes this is a logistic function:
$$
probability\_damage(durability) = \frac{1}{1+e^{0.01(durability-120)}}
$$
The actual distribution is discrete (since durability is an integer). I want to find the expected amount of uses that will cause the item to break (go from $360$ to $0$ durability).
My attempt to do was to consider each point (durability i) on the distribution its own experiment and essentially try to find the number of attempts that cause damage at that durability with $99$% certainty:
$$
\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{360}tries_i\ \ \ \ s.t.\ \ \ \ 1-(1-probability\_damage(i))^{tries_i}\ge0.99
$$
But I also know that the expected value of a geometric distribution is simply $1/p$, which would imply I should be doing:
$$
\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{360}\frac{1}{probability\_damage(i)}
$$
I assume I should be using the 2nd method, since expected value is not the same as value with high certainty? But I also feel like there's probably a better way to do this. Maybe directly from the original distribution, without having to treat each point separately?
I'm doing this for balance; I want to adjust the rate and x_offset of the distribution to get the "number of expected uses to go from $360$ to $0$ durability" that I want the item to have.
Any ideas/guidance?

Assuming that each instance of damage reduces durability by 1, and they are all independent, then you can use linearity of expectation, which says that the expectation of the sum is the sum of the expectations. Each individual expectation is a geometric expectation, so the formula $\sum 1/probability_damage(i)$ is correct.

You are right. Here's one way to look at it: let $T_{i,j}$ be a random variable representing the amount of uses required to go durability $i$ to durability $j$. Since losing one durability point is independent from losing another durability point we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{n,0}) = \mathbb{E}(T_{n,n-1}) + \mathbb{E}(T_{n-1,0}).$$
The amount of time it would take to go from $n$ durability to $0$ durability is however long it would take to go from $n$ to $n-1$ durability plus the amount of time it would take to go from $n-1$ to $0$.
The variables $T_{n,n-1}$ are all geometrically distributed with mean $p_n^{-1} = 1 + e^{0.01(n-120)}$. Then we can calculate the stopping time starting from $n$ durability by using another geometric series:
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{n,0}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (1 + e^{0.01(i-120)}) = n + e^{-1.19}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e^{0.01i}= n + \frac{e^{-1.19}(e^{0.01n}-1)}{e^{0.01}-1}.$$

Thanks @LeeFisher.
